# How to get concrete WSDL of WCF service?

Tags: wcf, wsdl

Could someone tell me how to get concrete WSDL from WCF service?

I know that ?wsdl give me an abstract WSDL, but don't know hot to get concrete.

---

Thanks for the answer, but it will not help. I've found solution. I need this concrete wsdl to  concrete wsdl to develop ESB solution and connect to back-end. I'm using Tibco AMX service grid for this and I build concrete wsdl using it's own mechanism.

Comment: Are you the owner/creator of the WCF service? The exposure of the WSDL is entirely up to whoever created it.

Comment: What do you mean by "abstract" vs. "concrete" WSDL?

Comment: Hi Justin, Yes, I'm owner of this service.

Comment: abstract wsdl contains contract definition (messages and operations only). Concrete WSDL contains more data. In addition to abstract it contains binding/transport specific information i.e. SOAP over Http/HTTPS/JMS.

Comment: I've never known WCF to return an abstract WSDL, by your definition.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are asking about publishing metadata.

Add `ServiceMetadata` behavior with `httpGetEnabled` attribute to your service:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior httpGetEnabled="true" >
      <serviceMetadata/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```